# DataSource Null Pointer Exception

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

When I instantiate a new Windows Form with a DataGridView I always seem to get a Null Pointer exception when I try to set the data source like so:

```
dgvOpenRequests.DataSource = lstRequest
```

Normally this would be an obvious problem but its the DataSource that is the null pointer and not the list I am setting it as. And once the exception error has disappeared (We have customer error handling.) the program displays exactly as I would expect it to.

Setting the data source happens after:

```
InitializeComponent()
```

Comment: Consider writing the binding code in the Form_Load event.

Comment: Please post more code. Reduce your problem into a separate project, where it does not reveal any of your production secrets and post it here.

Comment: Please append all relevant code. As of now, your question is _impossible_ to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)